# Java optional class method cannot be resolved

Tags: java, option-type

Given a class `Student` and its associated method `getGrade`

```
class Student{
    public int getGrade(int age){
        return age - 6;
    }
}
```

When I use the Optional class and call the function `getGrade`, it resulted in a compilation error with invalid method reference.

```
import java.util.Optional;
public class Classroom {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Student s = new Student();
        Optional<Student> optStu = Optional.ofNullable(s);
        System.out.println(optStu.map(optStu::getGrade));
    }
}
```

What do I need to change in the `sout` to print the age of the student?

Comment: What about the `age` argument?

Comment: how do you update to get the age argument? did `System.out.println(optStu.map(optStu::getGrade(7));` and didn't work

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
optStu.ifPresent(student -> System.out.println(student.getGrade()));
```

or

```
optStu.map(Student::getGrade).ifPresent(System.out::println);
```

#### Edit

My bad, I didn't notice `getGrade()` has a parameter.

In short, there is no way to use a lambda expression using `::` operator when `getGrade()` requires a parameter. You can only use the first method:

```
optStu.ifPresent(student -> System.out.println(student.getGrade(100)));
```

Comment: hi, for the second line, how do i add in the variable for age? For example, in the first line, the following code works:`optStu.ifPresent(student -> System.out.println(student.getGrade(11)));`

Comment: I believe in the second example it should be `Student::getGrade` not `optStu::getGrade`.

Comment: @JimGarrison You are right, I'm feeling a little sick today. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: Finally, your getGrade method does not seem to depend on any data within the Student object itself, only the parameter that is passed to it. That being the case, why is it important to have an instance of Student in order to call this method?

Comment: hello @TomDrake this was just an exercise to try out the `Optional` class, no functionality is tested.

Comment: @Jai no problem, I'm learning this stuff as I go and finding this little typo helped me learn something :-)